# Nginx in front of JBoss Domain Mode

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, jboss

I have JBoss EAP 7.2 servers which are running in domain mode:

10.10.26.61 jb-domain-arge (Domain Controller)

**10.10.26.62 jb-host-arge** (Host Controller)

**10.10.26.63 jb-host-arge2** (Host Controller)

and i have a reverse proxy in front of JBoss Host Controllers:

**10.10.26.60 jb-arge-apc**

JBoss Managed Servers are as follows:

**jb-host-arge**

SG01-H01 (HTTP Port: 2001)

http://10.10.26.62:2001/jboss-as-helloworld/HelloWorld

SG02-H01 (HTTP Port: 3001)

http://10.10.26.62:3001/SampleProject

SG03-H01 (HTTP Port: 4001)

http://10.10.26.62:4001/SampleWebApp

**jb-host-arge2**

SG01-H02 (HTTP Port: 2001)

http://10.10.26.63:2001/jboss-as-helloworld/HelloWorld

SG03-H02 (HTTP Port: 4001)

http://10.10.26.63:4001/SampleWebApp

I want to access all apps over 10.10.26.60, http 80 port, like:

http://10.10.26.60/jboss-as-helloworld/HelloWorld

http://10.10.26.60/SampleProject

http://10.10.26.60/SampleWebApp

And my **nginx.conf** is below:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream arge_2001 {
        server 10.10.26.62:2001;
        server 10.10.26.63:2001;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name arge_2001;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://arge_2001;
        }
    }
    
    upstream arge_3001 {
        server 10.10.26.62:3001;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name arge_3001;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://arge_3001;
        }
    }
    
    upstream arge_4001 {
        server 10.10.26.62:4001;
        server 10.10.26.63:4001;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name arge_4001;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://arge_4001;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed nginx.conf like this, and it works now:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream arge {
        hash $server_addr$server_port$request_uri consistent;
        
        server 10.10.26.62:2001;
        server 10.10.26.63:2001;
        server 10.10.26.62:3001;
        server 10.10.26.62:4001;
        server 10.10.26.63:4001;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 10.10.26.60;
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Graylog-Server-URL http://$server_name/;
            proxy_pass       http://arge;
        }
    }
}
```